# Absolutely reliable fixed TD width?

Tags: css, html, width, html-table

I'm right now fiddling around with table column widths. As the width attribute is deprecated in HTML5 I'm trying to set table column width by means of CSS. For some reason however this does not work reliably.

To be more specific...

I'd like to build a Gantt chart (some sort of schedule for those of you that haven't heard of it yet) by using a table. Each month is built by a number of columns that represent the number of days of the corresponding month. The header uses colspan to be spanned over all days of a month. Every day should be 10px width. So a TD that spans over 31 days (e.g. January) is decorated with the attribute style="width: 310px".

The project tasks moreover consist of three spanned columns: the first column is the unoccupied time between the beginning of the project and the date the task starts on, the second spanned column is the time the task is active and the third column is the time between the end of the task itself and the end date of the whole project.

I hope that explanation helps to get your head around my problem...

Weird about that is the fact that the columns somehow appear to ignore their width setting. It's visible in a DOM inspector like the one FireFox provides. It's not striked out so it's accepted and actually used in the DOM, but the calculated width of the TD does not reflect this setting. Some TDs are smaller, others wider than the width given by the style attribute.

And I simply don't see why.

So, is there a way to set the width of a spanned set of columns to a **fixed** value that is absolutely reliable and repeatable?

Comment: Do you have a demo or sample that displays the behavior you've observed?

Comment: I do. But in which way would you like to get it? HTML code? Or a screenshot? Since the data behind the Gantt chart is sort of confidential I can't provide you with a working example. I could create some dummy data for it to make such a working example. That would however take some time... I'll see what I can do.

Comment: have you tried setting `overflow: hidden` or `max-width`?

Comment: @SeveQ create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Alright, I'm working on a fiddle... give me a sec. I'm gonna edit this comment when I'm done.

Comment: @SeveQ: Best if you edited the question itself to include it.

Comment: Just as you wish :) No problem.

Comment: Umh, I guess, I've figured it out... Looks like I've got some rival width settings for single columns, right?

Comment: I love it when people say “Why use CSS for layout? It’s so easy with tables.”

Comment: I suspect (if you're not using it yet) that [`table-layout: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Table cell widths are calculated differently.

Unlike normal elements, where a `width:` setting is golden, a table cell can have a different width based on its contents. A table cell's content may never leak out. So if you have a longer cell, it would expand in width, overriding your `width:` setting, and thus "messing up" the rest of the cells as well (if you had a fixed width for all of them).

My recommendation: Give the `<table>` itself a width, and let it sort itself out. The results are usually optimal.

Comment: This would work if the content was the important thing I'd like to display. But it isn't. It's the cell width itself that carries the information. Remember, it's a gantt chart I'd like to display. The cells don't contain anything. They just get different background colours depending on their meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the provided Fiddle there are rival width settings in the THs and TDs. I've removed the width setting from every TD only leaving those in the THs in place. With that it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

In each TD element, insert a div and set the required width. That will insure that the width is fixed.

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td><div style="width: 200px;">Fixed 200px width</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

insert div or `<p>` tag in each td and set the width of div or `<p>` instead  of `<td>` itself..
i had same problem few days ago,but now it is working.